# background in header cuts on ipad/iphone and not correctly visible on iphone/ipad working fine on desktop and android

Tags: css, iphone, ipad

I have a problem my website it  runs fine on android and desktop but on ipad/iphone my background image seems very large and broken,I have added background-attachment:scroll but still cant fix it.
        Problem#2 when I have view my website iphone/ipad I can scroll horizontally and a white pace appears on the righthow to ix this.imean no horizonal scrolling,I have added overflow:hidden or overflow-x:hidden,

```
  body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    html,body {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }


    .header  {
                 background:url("Images/2.gif") no-repeat center center;

                width:100%;
                height:auto;
                padding-bottom:30px;
                background-attachment:scroll;
             -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        }
    website link : http://www.colddays.somee.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your viewport tag to the below to solve the width issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

For the background image, add this into your media query for both landscape and portrait:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.header {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:top center !important;
    background-size: cover;
}
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
.header {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:top center !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 500px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: I wish this couldwork after adding above nothing happens on the apple devices exactly same result as before..thanks for your reply

Comment: I think some thing on my website has large width but I have checked everything I have set is 100% is it possible if i write my code here and u see what is wrong @Nasherx